# Jquery Ui date time picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, jquerydatetimepicker

I am using [jquery date time picker](https://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/) and using `start date` and `end date`.

When selecting same date for `start date` and `end date` I do not want it to allow the `end date` time to be less than `start date` time.  How would I adjust my code?

```
$( "#fdate" ).datetimepicker({
     dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#tdate" ).datetimepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
  }
  }).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
     $( "#tdate" ).datetimepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
  onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
     $( "#fdate" ).datetimepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
  }
  }).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
});
```

here fdate is start date and tdate is end date and here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6x9sd9oq/5/) of the issue

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: we shouldnot able to select end date time less than start date time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the 'setOptions' method for each timepicker:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fdate" ).datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
        onShow: function () {
            this.setOptions({
                maxDate:$('#tdate').val()?$('#tdate').val():false,
                maxTime:$('#tdate').val()?$('#tdate').val():false
            });
        }
  }).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
  $( "#tdate" ).datetimepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
        onShow: function () {
            this.setOptions({
                minDate:$('#fdate').val()?$('#fdate').val():false,
                minTime:$('#fdate').val()?$('#fdate').val():false
            });
        }                    
  }).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```

Here is the [Modified Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6x9sd9oq/10/).

This is not perfect, but it will get you close, you may need to handle some of the formatting.  I used the 'onShow' event, but you could easily do it in the onClose, as well.  There is a small sample on their [official page](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)  called *Range between date#*.

Comment: What browser are you using and what isn't working?  It is working, as I wrote, close enough.  With some minor tweaks for your requirements it should be ok.  I checked in chrome.

Comment: Jason, I love it, but can it be corrected that when you click on start-date again, the dates ahead that have been blocked or end-date are not blocked?